# A problem from Munkres Analysis on Manifolds 26.7: Show the properties of tersor product characterize tensor product uniquely

Tags: analysis, tensor-products

[image]

The 4 properties are:[image]

I'm quite confused here since I don't know what the problem wants me to show. To be more specific, what do I need to show so that I can prove that the four properties stated in Theorem 26.4 characterize the tensor product uniquely?

For example, if some problem asks me to prove that a function $f:X \to Y$ is injective, I can show that when $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ we will have $x_1=x_2$. By the same idea, what should I show here? Thanks for the help,

Comment: @FShrike This is not the case. Munkres’ book define the tensor product as a binary operation for certain multilinear maps.

Comment: @azif00 Whoops. I took "tensor product" to mean the usual thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\odot$ is a binary operation for tensors on $V$ such that if $f$ is a $k$-tensor and $g$ an $l$-tensor, then $f \odot g$ is a $(k+l)$-tensor.

You need to prove that if $\odot$ satisfy the four given properties, then $\odot = \otimes$.
Below is a hint.

> If $f = \sum_I c_I\phi_I$ and $g = \sum_J d_J\phi_J$, then $$\textstyle f \odot g = \sum_{I,J} c_Id_J (\phi_I \odot \phi_J)$$ by (2) and (3). Use (4) to conclude that $f \odot g = f \otimes g$.